# Tor not starting: status is active (exited)

Tags: configuration, raspberry-pi

I'm starting tor using `sudo service tor start`. When checking `sudo service  tor status`, it's saying:

```
$ sudo service tor status
● tor.service - Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master)
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/tor.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Fri 2019-02-22 15:43:14 UTC; 6min ago
  Process: 24491 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 24491 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/tor.service

Feb 22 15:43:14 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master)...
Feb 22 15:43:14 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master).
```

In my torrc, I only added this:

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/sshd/
HiddenServiceVersion 3
HiddenServicePort 1234 127.0.0.1:9735
```

I switched on debugging, but there doesn't seem to be any problem:

```
Feb 22 15:43:15.000 [notice] Tor 0.3.5.8 opening log file.
Feb 22 15:43:15.518 [notice] Tor 0.3.5.8 running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.0j, Zlib 1.2.8, Liblzma 5.2.2, and Libzstd 1.1.2.
Feb 22 15:43:15.519 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Feb 22 15:43:15.519 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc".
Feb 22 15:43:15.519 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Feb 22 15:43:15.536 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Feb 22 15:43:15.536 [notice] Opened Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Feb 22 15:43:15.000 [warn] Your log may contain sensitive information - you're logging more than "notice". Don't log unless it serves an important reason. Overwrite the log afterwards.
Feb 22 15:43:15.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /usr/share/tor/geoip.
Feb 22 15:43:16.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /usr/share/tor/geoip6.
Feb 22 15:43:17.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0%: Starting
Feb 22 15:43:21.000 [notice] Starting with guard context "default"
Feb 22 15:43:22.000 [notice] Signaled readiness to systemd
Feb 22 15:43:22.000 [notice] Opening Socks listener on /run/tor/socks
Feb 22 15:43:22.000 [notice] Opened Socks listener on /run/tor/socks
Feb 22 15:43:22.000 [notice] Opening Control listener on /run/tor/control
Feb 22 15:43:22.000 [notice] Opened Control listener on /run/tor/control
Feb 22 15:43:22.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server
Feb 22 15:43:22.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network
Feb 22 15:43:22.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit
Feb 22 15:43:22.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Done
```

How can I find out why my tor is not starting?

Comment: Have you tried checking if SOCKS5 tor proxy works on `127.0.0.1:9050`?

Comment: In case you mean whether anything is already running on that port, then no, `lsof -i :9050` doesn't return anything

Comment: What kind of OS are you running and how did you install tor?

Comment: I'm using raspian and followed this guide for debian stretch: https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en

Comment: Try stopping tor using `sudo service tor stop` and run it from console: `tor`

Comment: @NeverMine17 Thanks, this way I found there is a problem in my config file.

Comment: tor.service - Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master) Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/tor.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled) Active: active (exited) since Sun 2019-10-27 04:08:28 EDT; 12s ago Process: 7514 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS) Main PID: 7514 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS) Oct 27 04:08:28 kali systemd[1]: Starting Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master)...
Oct 27 04:08:28 kali systemd[1]: Started Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master).
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
lines 1-8/8 (END)
need he

Comment: Have you tried sudo service tor@default status ?
Might as well be that tor IS operational even "service to" states to the contrary
HTH

Comment: Did you check your firewall??

Answer (score 0):

First of all look for some common configurations like Do you have changed user owner and group owner permissions for /var/lib/tor/sshd if it is root then change it tor toranon by using the command -:

chown -hR toranon:toranon /var/lib/tor/sshd

if still facing an issue comment down here.